# What would cause my 2014 Honda Civic Ex radio to require the unlock code?

Tags: honda, civic, audio

When I started my car today, it asked for the radio unlock code. I entered the code and everything was normal - the radio worked for the remainder of the trip, and when I turned the car off and on again, the radio continued to work.

What would cause it to require the code, as I want to avoid issues in the future. The car was sitting in a (hot) parking lot all day, and there was no evidence that the battery disconnected. The car started fine.

Comment: Just one of those stupid things, I'd assume. It just blooped the code. Not that I've had one do it before, but it happens. I know, this really isn't an answer, but there's really no telling (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

The unlock code should only prompt when a sudden power loss is detected (battery disconnect, Johnny's 5-finger discount,etc), of which you say there wasn't any. Might be an issue with your radio - you might report it to Honda to see if it is a known issue. It's probably covered by warranty.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your battery is starting to run low or is maybe an issue with your radio.

Comment: This answer could be much improved with a bit more information - for example, how could you test the battery to see if it's run down? What sort of issues could affect the radio, and how would you check for them?